# native unit tests in platformIO: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, unit-testing, platformio

I can't fix the following problem and need some help. I'm trying to write unit tests for an arduino (c++) project. When running the tests I receive the following error:

```
g++ -o .pio/build/native/test/test_internalTimefunctions.o -c -DPLATFORMIO=50002 -DUNIT_TEST -DUNITY_INCLUDE_CONFIG_H -Iinclude -Isrc -I.pio/build/native/UnityTestLib -I/Users/dakkar/.platformio/packages/tool-unity test/test_internalTimefunctions.cpp
g++ -o .pio/build/native/program .pio/build/native/test/test_internalTimefunctions.o .pio/build/native/test/tmp_pio_test_transport.o -L.pio/build/native .pio/build/native/libUnityTestLib.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_InternalTimefunctions", referenced from:
      test_isSleeptime() in test_internalTimefunctions.o
  "InternalTimefunctionsClass::isInSleeptime(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)", referenced from:
      test_isSleeptime() in test_internalTimefunctions.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
*** [.pio/build/native/program] Error 1
```

The minimal source for reproducing:
src/internal/internalTimefunctions.h

```
#include <cstdint>

class InternalTimefunctionsClass
{
    public:
        InternalTimefunctionsClass();
        ~InternalTimefunctionsClass();
        bool isInSleeptime(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t);
};

extern InternalTimefunctionsClass InternalTimefunctions;
```

src/internal/internalTimefunctions.cpp

```
#include "internalTimefunctions.h"

InternalTimefunctionsClass InternalTimefunctions = InternalTimefunctionsClass();

bool InternalTimefunctionsClass::isInSleeptime(uint8_t hours, uint8_t minutes, uint8_t startHour, uint8_t startMinute, uint8_t endHour, uint8_t endMinute)
{
    return false;
}
```

test/test_internalTimefunctions.cpp

```
#ifdef UNIT_TEST

#include <unity.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include "internal/internalTimefunctions.h"

void test_isSleeptime()
{
    uint8_t hours = 14;
    uint8_t minutes = 0;
    uint8_t startHour = 22;
    uint8_t startMinute = 0;
    uint8_t endHour = 6;
    uint8_t endMinute = 0;

    TEST_ASSERT_FALSE(InternalTimefunctions.isInSleeptime(hours, minutes, startHour, startMinute, endHour, endMinute ));
}


int main( int argc, char **argv) {
    UNITY_BEGIN();

    RUN_TEST(test_isSleeptime);

    UNITY_END();
}

#endif
```

platformio.ini

```
platformio]

[env:native]
platform = native
```

the command to run: `pio test -e native`

Whats suspicious in the error message:

```
  "InternalTimefunctionsClass::isInSleeptime(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)", referenced from:
```

why usigned char? it should be unsigned int? maybe that's the reason, why `isInSleeptime` can't be found (==unresolved symbol?)

EDIT: building under macos

```
❯ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: I just tried to run the tests on a native linux host. The error message there seems more plausible and assists my suspicion:
```/usr/bin/ld: test_internalTimefunctions.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `InternalTimefunctionsClass::isInSleeptime(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Hey @Dakkar, did you find out what the issue was?

Comment: Nope unfortunetely not. I still have no unittests running 

Answer (score 1):

> why usigned char? it should be unsigned int?

An 8-bit unsigned `int` is equivalent to `unsigned char`.
This isn't what is causing your problem though.

Try organising your library as per the PlatformIO [lib_dir](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/section_platformio.html#lib-dir) documentation.

For your example, you could do:

```
|--lib
|  |--internal
|  |  |--docs
|  |  |--examples
|  |  |--src
|  |     |- internalTimefunctions.cpp
|  |     |- internalTimefunctions.h
|- platformio.ini
|--src
|  |- main.c
|--test
   |--test_internal_time_functions
      |- test_internalTimefunctions.cpp
```

Things of particular interest to note:

- each unit test file needs its own folder
- place the shared code inside the `/lib/{library_name}/src` directory. I tried putting code into the `/lib/{library_name}` directory and that didn't work, so perhaps you are having a similar issue. This worked for me.

Comment: This is really strange. If I put files in `src` subdirs, it works on my microcontroller env. But it doesn't work for test env. If I put files in `lib` subdirs, it works for both MCU and tests. That's A BIG time wasting inconsistency, that I found about by hair-pulling experimentations…

Comment: Agree that this is odd. Had I not found this comment, I hadn't had any idea on how to solve this problem for me.